# manage strings with </> format in R

Tags: r

I have the following table:

[image]

and I want to manage the table with R to be like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Questions should be reproducible. This makes it easy for others to copy data easily so that potential solutions can be verified. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include your data from the output of `dput(your_data)`.

Comment: `df$number = readr::parse_number(df$number)`